# Migrating Views

Tags: 8, migrations

As Drupal 6 is officially EOL, I was planning to upgrade my Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8. My current site consists of lots of contents and views. I saw a discussion saying that Drupal 6-x-3.x can be migrated to drupal 8. But using the migrate, Drupal migrate UI, I was not able to do so. Is the best method to upgrade the site first to D7 and then to D8, other than creating the view manually? What about the D6 sites with views 6.x-2.x?

Comment: The migration path from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 is not complete. Chance is that something is not correctly migrated. I am not sure the migration from Drupal 6 is even supported.

Comment: Using the migrate modules of Drupal 8.1, I was able to migrate certain content types, users as well as contents. The page https://www.drupal.org/node/2488946  says that it is possible to migrate from 6.x-3.x to Drupal 8. But couldn't find any options for this.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've moved basic Node and User content from Drupal 6 to 8 using the drupal 8 migrate set of modules. Although to my knowledge this does move across Views and other site configuration.

Comment: Were you able to migrate views? using Drupal 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Migration of views is not currently supported - see https://www.drupal.org/node/2500547. Note that the destination D8 system would only be able to see views that are stored in the database (i.e., those created manually through the UI, not those provided in code).